# Does this combination of Battlemage Readiness & Spellsword Perfection with Dimensional Charge work?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, powers, swordmage

Can an assault swordmage combine Battlemage Readiness & Spellsword Perfection to gain a 4[W] immediate reaction whenever an enemy violates its mark?

> Battlemage Readiness (11th level): When you use your aegis of assault to teleport and make an attack, you can use a swordmage melee at-will attack power in place of the melee basic attack.

> Spellsword Perfection (30th level): Choose one sword mage encounter attack power that you know. You can now use that power as an at-will power rather than an encounter power.

> **Dimensional Charge (Swordmage Attack 27)**
> *Your blade opens a rift in reality, and you leap through to attack your enemy.*
> Encounter ✦ Arcane, Fire, Lightning, Teleportation, Thunder, Weapon
> Standard Action ✦ Melee weapon
> **Target:** One creature
> **Effect:** Before making the attack, you can teleport 10 squares to a space adjacent to the target. If you do, the attack is a charge.
> **Attack:** Intelligence vs. AC
> **Hit:** 4[W] + Intelligence modifier fire, lightning, and thunder damage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As wax eagle says, yes, this combination works precisely the way you want it to.

It is, however, substantially less impressive of a combination than you might expect it to be, or than the designers thought it would be.

By level 30, weapon dice are an almost irrelevantly small portion of your overall damage. A moderately optimized character should have a static damage modifier hovering around +50 damage per hit.

Level 20+ MBAs and At-Will weapon attacks already deal 2[W] of damage.

If you've got a longsword, an extra 2[W] is worth ~9 damage per swing. Even on a fullblade, it's only +13.

Now, that's nothing to scoff at, but compared to an additional damage instance, it doesn't hold a candle, and swordmages have access to a couple of multi-attacking encounter powers - namely Level 3's Lightning Clash and level 23's Lightning Bolt Charge.

At a combined 3[W]+2*modifiers, Lightning Bolt Charge should be substantially above 4[W]+1*modifiers, by somewhere around 30-45 damage depending on your optimization level, and it also gives you the flexibility to focus the attacks on one creature, or to teleport back to your original position/target after the initial attack.

Comment: An answer to my question plus some useful information. Thank you very much .

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's a Swordmage melee attack power, and Spellsword Perfection changes it's type from encounter to at-will so yes, you can do this.